# Mean and root mean square of a random variable

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, integral-inequality

Given a positive random variable $x$ with continuous probability density $f(x)$. What is the main difference between the ordinary mean value

$$\bar{x} = \int_0^\infty\,x\,f(x)\ dx$$

and the root mean squared expression

$$\tilde{x}= \sqrt{\int_0^\infty\,x^2\,f(x)\ dx}.$$

Are there any relations or inequalities between both of them?

Comment: The relation is $Var(X)= \tilde x  ^2-\overline x ^2$, if $f(x)=0 \ \forall \ \ x<0$

Comment: If $f(x)$ is symmetric around $0$ then the variance can be defined for a $f(x)$ where $x\in \mathbb R$

Comment: The positive reals.

Comment: OK, I´ve seen right now that you have already mentioned the information in the question. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that the variance $\sigma^2$ of $x$ is defined as follows:

$$\sigma^2 = \tilde{x}^2 - \bar{x}^2.$$

The variance is always non-negative. Therefore:

$$\sigma^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow \tilde{x}^2 - \bar{x}^2 \geq 0 \Rightarrow \tilde{x} \geq |\bar{x}|.$$

Comment: Is there something known in what cases equality holds?

Comment: @kaffeeauf This is always true. Check the definition of the variance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition).

Comment: Sorry, I asked for equality in $\tilde{x}\geq \bar{x}$.

Comment: This is an example for equality: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution

Comment: @kaffeeauf Since $\sigma^2 \geq 0$ is always true, and since $\sigma^2 = \tilde{x}^2-\bar{x}^2$, then also $\tilde{x} \geq |\bar{x}|$ is always true.

Comment: @kaffeeauf  If the random variable is a constant, then $\sigma =0$.